# Calculating standard deviation for each observation POWER BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a data set as follows

```
Date           TOTAL.LEAN.MASS
18/06/2020           43.15
20/08/2019           43.34
27/05/2019           41.4
10/12/2018           42.98
17/07/2018           42.47
9/05/2018            40.29
```

I want to be able to calculate the standard deviation for each TOTAL.LEAN.MASS score between each testing date.

for example: SD for the Thursday 18th of June 2020 in relation to the previous measurement of "TOTAL LEAN MASS" which is the Tuesday 20th August.

not sure if this can be done in DAX or if I need to run R script within POWER BI in order to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First create an index column in power query.

Then create a new column using the following dax formula:

```
STD = 
VAR __index = 'Table'[Index]
VAR __result = 
CALCULATE( 
    STDEV.P( 'Table'[TOTAL.LEAN.MASS] ),
    FILTER( 'Table',
        OR( 'Table'[Index] = __index, 'Table'[Index] = __index + 1 )  
    )
)
Return __result
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: do I place this code in the custom column dialog box or in the advanced editor in power query ? and is 'Table' the name of the data table ?

Comment: Put this code into a custom column. Table is the name of my table. Just replace that word for your table name.

Comment: when I chuck the code into the custom column formula, its giving me a "Token Eof expected" and highlights the "VAR __index = 'Table'" portion. not sure why this would be the case. Cheers

Comment: all good I was putting the code in power query windows not under modelling > new column, thanks again